# Java: Luna HSM Verify Sign using Public Key

Tags: public-key-encryption, hsm

Using Java API, I am trying to access Public key stored in Luna HSM. Even though I am able to print the corresponding public key label name, but when I am trying to get the public key, I am not able to get the reference to that public key. Here is the code snippet:

```
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Luna");
        ks.load(null, null); 
        lunaProvider = ks.getProvider();

        publicKey = (PublicKey) ks.getKey(alipayImpl.getHsmKeyStorePublicEntryName(), null);

        // ****************************************************************************
        // ** If the private keystore is not found, return original barcode string.  **
        // ****************************************************************************
        if (publicKey == null) {
            throw new Exception("Unable to acquire the Public Key " + alipayImpl.getHsmKeyStorePublicEntryName() + ", Hash will not be verified.");
        }
        // ***********************************************************
        // ** Create a Signature Object and sign the encrypted text **
        // ***********************************************************
        Signature signatureObject = Signature.getInstance(alipayImpl.getAlipaySignAlgorithm(), lunaProvider);

        signatureObject.initVerify(publicKey);
        signatureObject.update(signedMessage
                .getBytes(AlipayConstants.INPUT_CHARSET_VALUE));
        isValidSign = signatureObject.verify(Base64.decode(hash));
```

I am logging to HSM properly. While Accessing Private Key, I didnt have any issues. Is there any restriction on Luna HSM that access to public key is given only through Certificates?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is >

LunaKey lk= LunaKey.LocateKeyByAlias("publicKeyName");

But it is advisable to make the key persistent before querying HSM.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this :

```
final KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Luna");
keyStore.load(null, null);

final Certificate certificate = keyStore.getCertificate(alias);
if (certificate == null) {
   throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Certificate '%s' does not exists", alias));
}

final PublicKey publicKey = certificate.getPublicKey();
// TODO Working with the public key...
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java keystore there is no PublicKeyEntry and that's the reason why you're not able to access your public key.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.Entry.html

Java's KeyStore.KeyEntry interface has three implementing classes.

1. PrivateKeyEntry
2. SecretKeyEntry
3. TrustedCertificateEntry.

Java expects you to get retrieve a public key out of your certificate. Sebastien Vanmechelen has given you the perfect example on how to do that.

If by any chance, your Luna HSM partition does not have a X509 certificate then using LunaKey is the only alternative.